# Cmd key not working in Jupyter for iPython

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, jupyter-notebook

I'm running an *iPython* notebook using the `Jupyter notebook interface` on my Mac using *Chrome*. I'd like to be able to delete a cell, or a bunch of cells. The keyboard shortcut is `Cmd + D`, but when I press that it runs the Chrome "Add Bookmark" shortcut; a similar thing happens on Safari.

How can I fix this? (Not just for Delete, but for the other Cmd + keyboard shortcuts in the Jupyter interface).

Comment: The shortcut is typically `D,D` (i.e. press the D key twice), not `Cmd-D`. You need to be in *command mode* for this to work, rather than typing a D in the cell. If you're in edit mode, press Esc to go to command mode. It's set up like this precisely so that it doesn't interfere with browser shortcuts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The (command) in jupyter doesnt mean the command button in mac or ctrl button in windows. it means "command" mode.

You can enter the command mode either by pressing "Esc" or "ctrl-M"(when a cell is in focus) and then press "D,D" i.e Press D twice, to delete the cell.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Rohit answered.

I was having an issue where `Cmd + /` and `Cmd + a` weren't working (to comment a line and select all respectively) in Jupyter Notebook for AWS Sagemaker.

My solution was to restart Safari and now it's working properly.

Comment: This save my life!! I first kept getting weird websocket connection failures on FireFox, and then these `Cmd` problems on Safari....